# Using variables with a django template

Tags: python, django

I have a developed a filter which does alot of database queries in my django templete. I have several uses for the same filter with the same values which will provide the same result on the same templete. I wish to save the filter result in a variable within the templete so I can make sure I dont re-run the same queries over again.

I cant send this from my view because I am doing this filter call in a for loop for each object in my model.

an example of what I need can be seen in the url tag :

```
{% url 'path.to.view' arg arg2 as the_url %}
```

I need the "as" operation over a filter.

Comment: `I have a developed a filter` - Is what you developed a filter or a template tag? Your example, url, is a template tag (so are many of the other django examples that utilize the `as` keyword), I don't think that filters can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% with bla=arg|foo %}
  {% url 'view' bla %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: thats what I was after.. wondered how I couldnt find it in the documentation.

Comment: Great :) Sorry for the dense format, I was multitasking. Actually this pattern wasn't obvious to me until I started working on a code that's using it extensively.